# How to specify shipping_cost regarding all products in session?

Tags: php

I got a problem with the following script, which is listing all products from a session. There are products with different `$shipping_cost` (0.7 or 6.99).

If I have in my card:

> products with product_code<100 = shipping_cost should be 0.7,
>
> products with product_code>100 = shipping_cost should be 6.99,
>
> products with product_code<100 AND product_code>100 = shipping_cost keep 6.99.

```
    <?php

if(isset($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION["products"])>0){
$total          = 0;
$list_tax       = '';
$gs = 0.70;

$cart_box       = '<ul class="view-cart">';

foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){ //Print each item, quantity and price.
$product_name = $product["product_name"];
$product_qty = $product["product_qty"];
$product_price = $product["product_price"];
$product_code = $product["product_code"];
                                    
$item_price     = ($product_price * $product_qty);  // price x qty = total item price

$cart_box       .=  "<li class=\"view-cart-total\">$product_code &ndash; $product_name &ndash; Anzahl : $product_qty = <strong>" .number_format($item_price, 2, ",", "."). "&nbsp;".$currency."</strong></li>";   

$subtotal       = ($product_price * $product_qty); //Multiply item quantity * price
$total          = ($total + $subtotal); //Add up to total price
}


if($product_code < 100){
$shipping_cost = $gs;} //Gutschein-Versandkosten  
elseif($product_code > 100){
$shipping_cost = $shipping_cost;} //Gutschein-Versandkosten     
else {$shipping_cost = $shipping_cost;}                        

$grand_zw = number_format($total, 2, ",", "."); //Zwischensumme
$grand_total = $total + $shipping_cost; //Gesamtbetrag                          

foreach($taxes as $key => $value){ //list and calculate all taxes in array
$tax_amount     = ($grand_total - ($grand_total / 119 * 100)); //MwSt
$tax_item[$key] = $tax_amount;
$grand_total    = $grand_total + 0; 
}

foreach($tax_item as $key => $value){ //taxes List
$list_tax .= $key. ' ' .number_format($value, 2, ",", "."). '&nbsp;'.$currency. '<br />';
}
                                                        

$grand_netto = ($grand_total - $tax_amount);
$shipping_cost = ($shipping_cost)?'Versandkosten = '. number_format($shipping_cost, 2, ",", ".").' '.$currency.'<br />':'';

//Print Shipping, VAT and Total
...
?>
```

Problem is, if I have both products (product_code<100 and product_code>100) in the card, it regards only the last product I've given to the card.

So `$shipping_price` is either 0.7 or 6.99.

Comment: how product_code can be both >100 and <100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the shipping cost logic inside the foreach loop, this would be a possibility:

```
$shipping_cost = 0.7;    
$total_products_number = 0;

foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product) {
  ... here is your existing code of the foreach loop

  if($product_code > 100) {
    $shipping_cost = 6.99;
  }

  $total_products_number += $product["product_qty"];
}

if($total_products_number>1) {
  $shipping_cost = 6.99;
}
```

That way the default shipping costs are 0.7 and are only changed to 6.99 if there is a product with $product_code > 100 or if there is more than one product in quantity.

Comment: Okay, but default shipping_cost is always 6.99. It should just be 0.7 if only there is the single product  (product_code<100) in cart.

Comment: So if there are two products in the cart the shipping_costs are also 6.99, no matter the product code?

Comment: I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok I didn´t think about having 2 same products in cart, however I hope you can help out again ?!

Comment: I adjusted my answer by just counting the quantity and using that as the base for the shipping cost adjustment.